# Parse correctly XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have this XML link example:

https://np.tritondigital.com/public/nowplaying?mountName=KFRQFMAAC&numberToFetch=3&eventType=track&request.preventCache=1621376522745

Inside to the node "nowplaying-info-list" I have nodes called "nowplaying-info" and I need get each property for nodes "nowplaying-info", for example,

```
<nowplaying-info-list>
<nowplaying-info mountName="KFRQFMAAC" timestamp="1621894561" type="track">
<property name="cue_time_duration">
<![CDATA[ 05:07 ]]>
</property>
<property name="cue_time_start">
<![CDATA[ 1621894561283 ]]>
</property>
<property name="cue_title">
<![CDATA[ WIND OF CHANGE ]]>
</property>
<property name="program_id">
<![CDATA[ 20363 ]]>
</property>
<property name="track_artist_name">
<![CDATA[ SCORPIONS ]]>
</property>
</nowplaying-info>
<nowplaying-info mountName="KFRQFMAAC" timestamp="1621894008" type="track">
<property name="cue_time_duration">
<![CDATA[ 05:30 ]]>
</property>
<property name="cue_time_start">
<![CDATA[ 1621894008283 ]]>
</property>
<property name="cue_title">
<![CDATA[ ALL RIGHT NOW ]]>
</property>
<property name="program_id">
<![CDATA[ 18664 ]]>
</property>
<property name="track_artist_name">
<![CDATA[ FREE ]]>
</property>
</nowplaying-info>
</nowplaying-info-list>
```

For this response I need  to get in an array:

"cue_title"
"program_id"
"track_artist_name"
etc for each entry...

I trying using

```
simplexml_load_file( XML, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA );
```

but do not parse correcty the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$xml = simplexml_load_file( 'https://np.tritondigital.com/public/nowplaying?mountName=KFRQFMAAC&numberToFetch=3&eventType=track&request.preventCache=1621897306' );
echo $xml;
$items = array();

```
foreach($xml->{'nowplaying-info'} as $node)
    {
        // reset the array 
        $item = array();
        foreach ($node->property as $property){
            //${$property['name']} =$property;
            //echo "\n".${$property['name']};
            $item[(string) $property['name']] =(string) $property;
        }
        $items[] = $item;
       

    }
    
print_r($items);
```

// output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cue_time_duration] => 05:03
            [cue_time_start] => 1621898862311
            [cue_title] => WANTED DEAD OR ALIVE
            [program_id] => 20085
            [track_artist_name] => BON JOVI
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cue_time_duration] => 05:26
            [cue_time_start] => 1621898331404
            [cue_title] => ENTER SANDMAN
            [program_id] => 20496
            [track_artist_name] => METALLICA
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cue_time_duration] => 04:19
            [cue_time_start] => 1621898074316
            [cue_title] => LIMELIGHT
            [program_id] => 18449
            [track_artist_name] => RUSH
        )

)
```

Comment: I need read this one from the URL, example:

`$xml = simplexml_load_string( 'https://np.tritondigital.com/public/nowplaying?mountName=KFRQFMAAC&numberToFetch=3&eventType=track&request.preventCache=1621897306' );`

And this getting some errors

Comment: @AndrésGómez I updated my answer, use `simplexml_load_file(URL);`

Comment: This works fine and get the first item, Is there any way to iterate to each Item called "nowplaying-info" nodes?

Comment: Ok, it's set to fill an array, I updated my answer. If it works for you, please mark it as solved by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Thanks